# Set new rails environment variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is probably a easy question but cant seem to find a straight answer. I'm trying to set up a mailer and config the smtp settings and I was wondering how do you set new environment variables for

```
:user_name      => ENV['GMAIL_USERNAME'],
:password       => ENV['GMAIL_PASSWORD']
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: are you trying to set environment variabel for heroku ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set them up and keep them secret using the [Figaro Gem](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro)

Add it to your `Gemfile` and `bundle`. Then install Figaro:

```
bundle exec figaro install
```

Once it's installed, you'll have a new file called `application.yml` in your `config` folder

You can create environment variables there and they're ignored by Git so your secrets won't get published.

You can set different variables for different environments if you want.

```
development:
  GMAIL_USERNAME: 'yourname@gmail.com'
  GMAIL_PASSWORD: notaRE41p4ssw0rD

production:
  GMAIL_USERNAME: 'yourproductionname@gmail.com'
  GMAIL_PASSWORD: notaRE41p4ssw0rD317h3R
```

To push them to Heroku:

```
$ figaro heroku:set -e production
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [dotenv gem](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) as well. Figaro seems to be poorly maintained at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Another option beside accepted answer, for heroku setting environment variabel can be setup using heroku terminal command as follow

```
heroku config:set GMAIL_USERNAME=******* 
heroku config:set GMAIL_PASSWORD=******
```